# Cannot connect to CVS repo from outside lan

Tags: cvs, ubuntu-11.10

I recently installed cvs onto by ubuntu server (11.10).  I am able to connect to my repos via eclipse IDE from within my lan by using the server name.  However, when I use the IP address instead I cannot connect.

This error is given:  "Cannot connect to host: Connection refused".

I have port forwarding on and can connect to apache2, mysql, etc. from outside my lan just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I was Googling a bit.

http://kulitkulit.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/installation-cvs-ubuntu-jaunty/

Comment: This does not help me at all.  The pserver is running and i can connect using the server name, but when it comes though my router its not allowed..